# Problem with access to ArcGIS Server Manager

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

ArcGIS For Server 10.0

*Firefox can not establish a connection to the server.* (Error in all browsers) ArcGIS Server Manager problem

In ArcCatalog i can connect but can't *start*

*Configuration MapServer can not be started.*

Also in computer management missing *Local Users and Groups*

What is my fault? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug with Arcserver Manager in the newer versions Firefox and chrome. ESRI released a patch [here](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/66/metaid/2054)

Comment: But my version is 10.0. Is it suitable?

Comment: And in Internet Explorer too not worked.

Comment: I would try it out and see